# How to create a New Page on Prestashop 1.7 Child Theme

Tags: themes, prestashop-1.7

I want to create a new page on my prestashop. I dont want to use the CMS to create the page, I need essentially a totally new page.

I have tried duplicating current .tpl's and renaming them - but I can never navigate to them - what is the url to access the new template?

```
E.g. say my site is www.xyz.com the "my account" template, sits under template/customer/my-account.tpl this my account page is normally accessed at xyz.com/my-account
```

I want a new but similar page - so I duplicate this template, rename it to my-account-new and change something in it, why can you not access the new template by change the URL to end with my-account-new - I just get a 404.

What am I missing? 
Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new front controller in a custom module :
ModuleName/controllers/front/ControllerName.php

Then your new controller is a class that should be defined like :

```
Module::getInstanceByName('<ModuleName>');

class <ModuleName><ControllerName>ModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
```

Then you add the method

```
public function initContent(){
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('<templateFolder>/<templateName>');
}
```

You can now navigate to the template by going to index.php?fc=module&module=ModuleName&controller=ControllerName

So in this example replace every ModuleName with the name of your custom module and ControllerName with the name of your controller (for example MyCustomModule and MyCustomController).

The template will be in the your theme folder for example you can add customAddress in themes/ThemeName/templates/customer/customAddress.tpl

in which case the call to setTemplate would become :

```
 $this->setTemplate('customer/customAddress');
```

I hope this helps.